# Set up PyCharm for PyQGIS 3 development

Tags: python, pyqgis, pycharm

I'd like to setup PyCharm for PyQGIS 3 development. There is [a good guide](https://nathanw.net/2014/05/10/setting-up-pycharm-for-pyqgis-and-qt/) for PyQGIS 2, but those steps only make python 2 available, and I want to use python 3. Selecting python3 as interpreter returns an error:

```
Cannot setup a python SDK at python 3.6.0 (C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\python3.exe).
The SDK seems invalid
```

My .bat file has the following config:

```
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W64
SET QGISNAME=qgis
SET QGIS=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\%QGISNAME%
SET QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%QGIS%
SET PYCHARM="C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.3.2\bin\pycharm.exe"

CALL %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat

SET PATH=%PATH%;%QGIS%\bin
SET PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin;%PYTHONPATH%

start "PyCharm aware of QGIS" /B %PYCHARM% %*
```

Comment: Basile, I had success following Gary Sherman's excellent how-to located here: http://spatialgalaxy.net/2018/02/13/quick-guide-to-getting-started-with-pyqgis3-on-windows/. Hopefully it will help you as well. -cm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basile, as a P.S. to my comment, my batch file (pyqgis.cmd) looks like this:

```
@echo off
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W64
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\o4w_env.bat
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\apps\grass\grass-7.4.0\etc\env.bat
@echo off
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass-7.4.0\lib
path %PATH%;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Qt5\bin
path %PATH%;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python36\Scripts

set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python
set PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python36

set QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Qt5\plugins\platforms
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis

start "PyCharm Aware QGIS" /B "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.4\bin\pycharm64.exe" %*
REM cmd.exe /K cd /d "C:\
```

and  my python interpreter is located here:

```
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python36\python.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer above from cm1 works well with PyCharm 2018. However, with PyCharm 2019 (2019.1 and 2019.2) it won't work anymore.

See also
[PyCharm 2019 is not working with QGIS anymore](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317332/pycharm-2019-is-not-working-with-qgis-anymore)