# Setting the Python interpreter in PyCharm 2020.2.3, using QGIS 3.10.11. Error "No module qgis exists"

Tags: qgis, pycharm

I'm trying to find out where I'm going wrong in trying to set up PyCharm to make standalone QGIS Python scripts.

The very first step in the tutorial is "from qgis.core import *"

I've tried each Python installed in the QGIS folder, they all have no module named qgis.
[image]

The error is the same

[image]

Comment: Please don't include critical textual information as images.  They are not always legible on all client platforms, and can't be searched by others to find your answer.

Comment: You need to tell PyCharm where your PyQGIS files are located (https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/317341/21355) and have QGIS installed using the OSGeo4W installer. Other resources which may help: https://haifengniu.com/en/post/pyqgis-pycharm/how-to-set-environment-for-pyqgis-3-in-pycharm/ and https://woostuff.wordpress.com/2014/05/10/setting-up-pycharm-for-pyqgis-and-qt/